# Can I edit the individual Pipeline link-texts/headings on BitBucket in the "X of Y builds passed" section?

Tags: yaml, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I have 2 Pipelines running on a repo that were configured using bitbucket-pipelines.yml. They show up on the side of the BitBucket interface like this-
`Pipeline #807 for branch-name-here`
`Pipeline #808 for Pull Request #370`

I'd like to make these messages more descriptive. Both of these pipeline's `script`s have a `name` as per the yml file but I guess that alone doesn't help.